# Infinite series of converging sequence: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n2^n}=\ln 2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

How can I prove the following equality;
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n2^n}=\ln 2\,.$$

Comment: $$- \ln(1-x) = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{x^{n}}{n}$$ with a particular value of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$\frac1{1-r}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$$

Integrate both sides with respect to $r$ from $0$ to $x$ to get that

$$-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$$

Now proceed to use $x=1/2$.

Comment: The right idea. In an exam I would insist that you justify, why it is ok to integrate this infinite series term-by-term.

Comment: Because $\sum_{n=0}^{k}r^k$ converge uniformly to $\frac{1}{1-r}$ in $[-a,a]$ for $|a|<1$ as $k\rightarrow\infty\,.$

Comment: @David I think you ought to check that?  I think we need DCT here.